# How to input data into an extremely simple table with one entity in this case "Name"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

All I want is to input data into a SQL table called `ProductTable` with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductTable] (
    [ID]   INT           NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

I have model class called `TableModel.cs` in `Model` folder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Father.Models
{
        [Table("ProductTable")]
        public class ProductTable
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
}
```

and another class called `TableModelEntities.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Father.Models
{
    public class TableModelEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ProductTable> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my controller `TableController.cs` I want to fill this table with a product

```
using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet;
using Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth;
using WebMatrix.WebData;
using Father.Filters;
using Father.Models;
using ProductLayer;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Father.Controllers
{
    public class TableController : Controller
    {
        TableModelEntities dbproducts = new TableModelEntities();

        public ActionResult Table()
        {
            ProductTable product = new ProductTable();
            product.Name = "AAA";
            dbproducts.Products.Add(product);

            return View(product);
        }
    }
}
```

But nothing happens. Can you guys help me do this? I guess I miss something big.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a call to SaveChanges if you want to have your changes pushed to the database:

```
public ActionResult Table()
    {
        ProductTable product = new ProductTable();
        product.Name = "AAA";
        dbproducts.Products.Add(product);

        dbproducts.SaveChanges();

        return View(product);

    }
```

EDIT: I really don't think your model will work without you ID column being reflected in your `ProductTable` class. I would try adding the ID column and seeing if that works.

Also, make sure you are disposing of your DB context correctly. Check this blog post for some good details:

http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/03/27/managing-entity-framework-dbcontext-lifetime-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

You could make sure your controller is disposing of the context, or just create one for that update using a `using` statement

```
using (TableModelEntities dbproducts = new TableModelEntities())
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: still nothing changes when i ShowTableData also when this changes are going to happen actually when this ActionResult is happening? sorry im new to mvc have read some stuff but questionning is kinda easy for me

Comment: @spirit_seller you are pointing to another DB instead the one where you created the table. Look at your web.onfig to see

Comment: what should i check/write in web.config to make it work
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Father-20140205215821;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Father-##########.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: @spirit_seller Couple of questions for more info: Have you confirmed your DB connection works? What happens if you put data in manually and use your context to retrieve it? Also, is your ID column an auto-increment column?

Comment: @SimonC well its and ASP.NET MVC 4 WEB APPLICATION and it starts with already created registration tables/models/controllers so i guess the DB works.and for the ID columns the code for the table is above so ID column setted as set primary key

Answer (score 0):

You should save to commit the changes:

```
dbproduct.SaveChanges()
```

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx):

> SaveChanges   Saves all changes made in this context to the underlying database.